# First next and first last based on number

Tags: php, arrays, date, foreach

I have some array in PHP like this

```
$numbers = array('1','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','11','123','89');
```

And current number that can be random like this

```
$currentNumber = 32;
```

What I need is to output only first number from array that is lower than `$currentNumber` and first higher number from array that is bigger than `$currentNumber`

I know i can output all lower and all bigger, put only i need one :(

```
foreach ($numbers as $number){
     if ($number > $currentNumber){
          echo $number .' Number is bigger';
     }
     else{
          echo $number .' Number is lower';
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
<?php
$numbers = array('1','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','11','123','89');

$currentNumber = 32;

$firstLowerNumber = null;
$firstBiggerNumber = null;

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if ($number < $currentNumber && $firstLowerNumber === null) {
        $firstLowerNumber = $number;
    }
    if ($number > $currentNumber && $firstBiggerNumber === null) {
        $firstBiggerNumber = $number;
    }
}

echo $firstBiggerNumber === null ? 'No number is bigger than ' . $currentNumber . PHP_EOL : $firstBiggerNumber . ' Number is bigger' . PHP_EOL;
echo $firstLowerNumber === null ? 'No number is lower than ' . $currentNumber . PHP_EOL : $firstLowerNumber .' Number is lower' . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will find only first number from array that is lower than $currentNumber and first higher number from array that is bigger than $currentNumber

```
$firstLowestNum=$firstHigherNum=null;
$currentNumber=32;

$numbers = array('1','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','11','123','89');

foreach ($numbers as $number){
 if ($number > $currentNumber && is_null($firstHigherNum)){
  $firstHigherNum =$number;
}
else if(is_null($firstLowestNum)){  
  $firstLowestNum =$number;
}
}
var_dump($firstLowestNum,$firstHigherNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $numbers = array('1','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','11','123','89');
$currentNumber = 32;


$greater_numbers= array();
$lower_numbers= array();
foreach ($numbers as $number){
 if ($number > $currentNumber){

  array_push($greater_numbers,$number);
}
else{
 array_push($lower_numbers,$number);
}
}
sort($greater_numbers);
sort($lower_numbers);
echo "first greater number".$greater_numbers[0];
echo "first lowest number".end($lower_numbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your array ascending and get the first lower element and it will be the lowest in this array.

Then sort your array descending and get the first higher element and it will be the highest in this array.

```
$numbers = array('1','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','11','123','89');

$input=32;
$max=0;
$min=0;
sort($numbers);
foreach($numbers  as $index=>$value){
    if ($value < $input){
        $min=$value;
        break;
    } 
}

rsort($numbers);
foreach($numbers  as $index=>$value){
    if ($value > $input){
        $max=$value;
        break;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `$numbers` is not sorted.

```
$numbers = array('1','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','11','123','89');
$currentNumber = 32;

$closestLower = min($numbers);//or some minimum constant as lower bound
$closestHigher = max($numbers);//or some maximum constant as upper bound

foreach($numbers as $number){
    if($number < $currentNumber && $number > $closestLower){
        $closestLower = $number;
    }
    if($number > $currentNumber && $number < $closestHigher){
        $closestHigher = $number;
    }
}
echo $closestLower."\n";
echo $closestHigher."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

`first number from array that is lower than $currentNumber` I assume you need the first value that is found right in the order (There may be others if we move ahead but you need first one).

A quicker way is to iterate over the array twice. Break the loop when you get the value.

```
 $currentNumber = 32;
 $min=0; 
 $max=0;
 foreach($numbers as $value){
 if($value<$currentNumber){
    $min = $value;
    break;
   }
 }

foreach($numbers as $value){
  if($value>$currentNumber){
  $max = $value;
  break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your $min value will be incorrect if there is more than one element in the array that is smaller than the $currentNumber.

Comment: @Tom i guess that's what the user is asking `first number from array that is lower than $currentNumber`

Comment: Ah, you may well be right - @miomir-dancevic, could you clarify?

Comment: @Tom I have updated my answer as well and I have mentioned that point

Answer (score 0):

```
$smaller = $bigger = null;

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if ($number < $currentNumber) {
        $smaller = $number;
    }

    if ($number > $currentNumber) {
        $bigger = $number;
        break;
    }
}

echo $smaller, $bigger;
```

Of course, this will only work if the `$numbers` array is sorted. If this isn't guaranteed, use the [sort](http://php.net/sort) function first.

Comment: It will break the loop if the first number is greater than current number

Comment: What would the better behaviour be? Surely, that is what would be desirable in the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is sorted, just use two flags indicating if you've found the lower and higher numbers. No need for iterating the array twice.

```
    $lowerNumberFound= false;
    $higherNumberFound = false;
    foreach ($numbers as $number){
     if (!higherNumberFound && $number > $currentNumber) {
         echo $number .' Number is bigger';
         $higherNumberFound = true;
    }
    else if(!lowerNumberFound && $number < $currentNumber {
        echo $number .' Number is lower';
        $lowerNumberFound= true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use below way

```
$numbers = array('1','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','11','123','89');

$currentNumber = 32;

sort($numbers);
foreach($numbers as $key=>$row){
    if($currentNumber <$row){
        break;
    }

}
echo 'lower Number = '. $numbers[$key==2?$key-2:$key-1].'<br>';
echo 'Greater Number = '. $numbers[$key].'<br>';
```

check last value with current value if it's same, it needs some more twist

Comment: Fine unless the `$currentNumber` is in the array - in which case, `$numbers[$key - 1]` isn't necessarily lower.

Comment: why u voted down buddy please check by doing current number = 0 and yhea please check by keeping two values in array too

Comment: As I said in my comment - `$numbers = array(1, 32, 33);` will break this code.

Comment: yhea please have a updated code and let me know if anything else

Comment: Your update will still be wrong as it will return the greater number as 32 in the case I just provided.

Comment: yhea buddy keeping in mind array is fine enough large, but any updated it , lastly if the value found in last one more twist to code done i.e. check last value of array with current number. now ur case and question case working

Comment: What about array(1,2,32,32,32,32,45,101)? The logic of your method is still off course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122488/discussion-between-tom-and-kool-mind).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $numbers = array('1','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','11','123','89');

    $currentNumber =7;
    $low_number=$high_number= false;

        foreach ($numbers as $number){

         if (!$high_number && $number > $currentNumber) {
             echo $number .' Number is bigger</br>';
             $high_number = true;
        }
        else if(!$low_number && $number < $currentNumber) {
            echo $number .' Number is lower</br>';
            $low_number= true;
        }

        }
    ?>
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
        <?php

        $numbers = array('1','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','11','123','89');

        $currentNumber =7;

       $new = array_flip($numbers);

            foreach ($new  as $key=>$number){

                    if($key==$currentNumber)
                    {

                        echo prev($new)."Number is lower</br>";

                        echo next($new)."Number is bigger</br>";

                        break;
                    }

            }

    ?>
```

Comment: It returns 1 Number is lower</br>8 Number is bigger</br>

Comment: that's your expected result na @MiomirDancevic

Comment: No first smaller and first bigger

Comment: if $currentNumber =7 mean 6 Number is lower  and 8 Number is higer is it ?

Comment: Yes, that how it must be

Comment: i have one doubt your $currentNumber  always present in that array ? @MiomirDancevic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122501/discussion-between-jothi-and-miomir-dancevic).

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers = array('1','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','11','123','89');
$currentNumber=32;

sort( $numbers );
while( list( $key, $value ) = each( $numbers ) ){
    if( $currentNumber > $value ){
        $low=$value;
        break;
    }
}
while( list( $key, $value ) = each( $numbers ) ){
    if( $currentNumber < $value ){
        $high=$value;
        break;
    }
}
echo 'Low:'.$low.', High:'.$high;
```

Comment: Not good because it return 0?? If number is 32, it must return 11, and 89

Comment: Your question should therefore be re-phrased because it seems what you actually wanting to do is get the numbers that are closest to `$currentNumber`